# "Class not registered" exception when using the “AxDrawingControl” from the dll “AxInterop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll” (v4.0.30319)

Tags: visio

I am getting the below exception when using the `AxDrawingControl` from the dll `AxInterop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll` (v4.0.30319) in my application:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
HResult=-2147221164
Message=Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
Source=System.Windows.Forms
ErrorCode=-2147221164

The stackTrace:

   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   at TestVisOcxAxDrawing.VisioTestForm.InitializeComponent() in C:\ TestVisio\TestVisOcxAxDrawing\VisioTestForm.Designer.cs:line 55
  InnerException:
```

- The application is configured as “Any CPU” in the Configuration Manager -> “Active Solution Platform”
- The app is throwing the above error when it is executing as a 64bit application in Windows8 64bit OS.
- Visio installation is Professional 2010, x86 version.

  Here are my observations so far:

  1. The visio drawing control loads fine when visio x64 version is installed.
  2. It also works fine if the “Active Solution Platform” is changed to x86 version.

Unfortunately both the above work-arounds are not possible in my case as it is a click once application and the clients could be running on any version of windows with any Visio version installed.

Questions:

1. Can the application be configured as "Any CPU" and still support both visio 32 and 64 bit versions ?
2. Are there any alternatives/best practices to handle such scenarios ?

   - eg:  releasing 32 and 64 versions of the app separately ?
   - Or is it possible to ship both 64 and 32 bit versions of the Visio dlls along with the app and switch between them when an error happens?

Steps to recreate

1. Create a new Windows form project in VS2010 on a machine with 64 bit Windows OS.
2. Configure the project as `Any CPU` in the Configuration Manager -> `Active Solution Platform`.
3. Right click on the toolbox and click `Choose Items` -> navigate to `COM Components` tab -> Check `Microsoft Office Visio 14.0 Drawing Control`.
4. The Visio drawing control will appear on the toolbox now.
5. Drag the `Microsoft Office Visio 14.0 Drawing Control` control into a form and press `F5`.
6. The `Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))` error will throw up.

Thank you,
Regards,
Praveen

Comment: Question 1: NO. compile for x86
Question 2: some applications have to be x86 because components are differ. But when everything compiled for x86 it will work fine on both 32 and 64 bit systems